# SharePoint 2013 provider-hosted app with FAB authentication model

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps, fba

I am using FBA authentication model into one of SP WebApplications in our SP 2013 farm to give users outside the AD, accessibility to one of SPSite so they can access the lists & Libraries and run sharepoint apps ..

for that I installed & configured the components necessary to enable & manage the FBA users easily by following the steps in the great article made by Sean Earp

[Configuring SharePoint 2013 Forms-Based Authentication with SQLMemberShipProvider](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ptsblog/archive/2013/09/20/configuring-sharepoint-2013-forms-based-authentication-with-sqlmembershipprovider.aspx)

Now I am able to acess my SPsite using FBA users and see the Libraries & Apps inside the SharePoint site. and when I try to access one of the provider-hosted apps, the request redirected to the remote web using the FBA account correctly, but I didn't have any access to web-app or host-app from the remote website.

Is there any restriction to access sharepoint-hosted apps using FBA authentication model in SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to made some entry in your remote IIS site's web.config file.
Check below link. It might be helpful for you
http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-create-a-Provider-Hosted-Application-on-Form-Based-Authentication-WebApplication-in-SharePoint-2013

Comment: The entry is already in place, in fact I am able to access the same remote website from the SPsite by the AD users without no restrictions, the issue raised up only when I use FBA users to access the remote web from SPsite.
Thanks anyway for your add, and I think I should look more into the authentication model.  

N.B: the authentication model of my SPSite is using Windows Azure ACS to authenticate the webApps running in the SPSite, so my SharePoint App model is using S2S with OAuth flow, which I am not sure if that model will affect somehow the authentication process of FBA users.